# adding lat/long points to USGS Conic Projection in QGIS

Tags: projection, qgis

I'm very new to QGIS. I have a map of the United States that I've projected into Equal Area Albers (ESRI 102039). However, I have around 2,400 lat/long points spread across the US that I need to put on that map. Now, when I add it, they are TINY, i.e., if I zoom into the United states a LOT, I see them as distinct points, but otherwise, it is just one point, i.e., they are not projected correctly.

I assume this is because the actual CSV file has the locations in lat/long, which doesn't work (apparently) with Albers. Any tips for how to project it correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that you have assigned the wrong CRS to the CSV data when you imported it. You say it is LAT/LON data so it should be in degrees and have a range of values for latitude between -65 and -170 and longitude between 17 and 71 (or so). If you have told QGis that these values are in Equal Area Albers and are measured in metres then they will be plotted somewhere near the centre of the map (the bounds are of the order of millions of metres).

So to cure this you need to make sure that QGis "knows" that the CSV file/layer is in EPSG:4326, you can right click on the layer and go down to the `Set CRS` sub menu and the set it to EPSG:4326 there.

In future when importing CSV files be sure to set the CRS correctly in the import window.

Once, QGis is knows the projection of the layer it will have no problem reprojecting your data to match your map and your points will be in the correct place.